# How to convert a date string to the current time zone on the command line?

Tags: macos, terminal

How can I convert a date/time string, e.g. `2011-11-13 08:11:02 +0000`, to my local time zone on the command line?

Comment: Don't hesitate to add different answers, but please remember that OS X has BSD `date`, not GNU `date`. The options are quite different.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use `date -jf "<input format>" "<input value>" +"<output format>"`.

The following converts a UTC date to my local time zone (CET):

```
$ date -jf "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z" "2011-11-13 08:11:02 +0000" +"%Y_%m_%d__%H_%M_%S"
2011_11_13__09_11_02
```

If you specify the same date format for both input and output, you will only convert the time to your local time zone. But, as in the example, you can combine that with a format conversion.

Comment: The target time zone can be changed by temporarily setting `$TZ`: `TZ=EST date -jf %H%z 23+0100 +%I%p` → `05PM`

Answer (score 0):

If you're like me an keep forgetting the date options, here's a function based on Daniel Beck's answer that you can add to your `.profile` or `.zshrc`, etc.

I find myself needing to convert from two different date formats frequently, so the first line attempts to convert one format, and if that fails it silences the error and tries the other format.

```
utcdate() {
    # first try Apache access log format
    date -jf "%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S %z" "$* +0000" +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z" 2>/dev/null ||
    # second try MySQL style
    date -jf "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z" "$* +0000" +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z"
}
```

Then you can run it like:

```
utcdate 25/Sep/2023 18:40:20
```