# When was the latest successful Time Machine backup?

Tags: macos, terminal

How can I determine the date and time of the latest Time Machine backup from the command line, so I can e.g. display it in an AppleScript dialog or via Growl's `growlnotify`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Time Machine state information is stored in `/private/var/db/.TimeMachine.Results.plist`. Use `defaults` to read the `BACKUP_COMPLETED_DATE` value:

```
$ defaults read /private/var/db/.TimeMachine.Results BACKUP_COMPLETED_DATE
2011-11-13 08:28:07 +0000
```

It's in UTC, but you can easily [convert it to your local time zone](https://superuser.com/questions/356898/how-to-convert-a-date-string-to-the-current-time-zone-on-the-command-line).

---

To display it using `growlnotify`, run something like the following:

> `/usr/local/bin/growlnotify -m "$( date -jf "%F %T %z" "$( defaults read /private/var/db/.TimeMachine.Results BACKUP_COMPLETED_DATE )" +"%d.%m.%Y %H:%M" )" "Latest Time Machine Backup"`

[image]

Comment: Any idea how to create a hook so that this is displayed when a backup finishes?

Comment: @slhck Sure, use `launchd` and the `WatchPaths` directive to start a small shell script that compares the current with the previous (stored somewhere) output of `defaults`, and only calls `growlnotify` if it changed. Due to OS X's atomic saves, the file is recreated each time it's written: Verify using `stat /private/var/db/.TimeMachine.Results.plist`, all of `ctime`, `atime` `mtime` and `btime` are the same.

Comment: I tested this: It works when watching `/private/var/db/` (the directory).

Answer (score 2):

Another option (requires the backup volume to be mounted): `date -jf "%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S" "$(tmutil latestbackup | sed 's|.*/||')" +"%F %T"`

Comment: Didn't know about `tmutil` -- and using that I can start the backup any time. Thanks for the answer! The connection requirement is pretty inconvenient unfortunately for the purpose of this question.